# Should I avoid creating two relations between two nodes in unidirectional mapping?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've already understood that in order to get unidirectional mapping I simply can ignore direction when writing queries. However, I have a question about **inserting data**.

```
UserA -[friend]-> UserB
UserA <-[friend]- UserB
```

Should I avoid create secondary friend relation in other direction? If so, how can I achieve this?

I mean, how to write in cypher "creation relation only of there is no same relation in other direction"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to MERGE the relationship. Unlike CREATE, you can omit the direction of a merged relationship:

```
MERGE (userA)-[:FRIEND]-(userB)
```

This will check for an existing relationship in either direction, and if none exists it will create one with an arbitrary direction.

As for whether to create a second relationship in the opposite direction, avoid that if you can, unless it has a distinct meaning compared to the first relationship.

For example, a person can be in love with another person, but that doesn't mean the other person loves them back, a second relationship would be needed to cement that.